# show the target of current directory (symbolic link)

Tags: command-line, symbolic-link, cd-command

I'm in directory `~/a` which is a symbolic link to `~/b/c`. My prompt looks like:

```
~/a$
```

But I hope to `cd` to `~/b/c`.

```
~/a$ cd .
~/a$
```

It doesn't work. What's the right way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a way of changing to the target of the given symbolic link:

```
cd -P .
```

Here is how it works

```
user@host:~/tmp$ ls 
@a b
user@host:~/tmp$ file a
a: symbolic link to `b/c'
user@host:~/tmp$ cd a
user@host:~/tmp/a$ cd .
user@host:~/tmp/a$ cd -P .a
user@host:~/tmp/b/c$
```

You can alias it to

```
cdl='cd -P'
```

From the bash manual:

> The **-P** option says to use the physical  directory structure  instead  of following symbolic links

Comment: pretty cool. it's a strange that I haven't tried to consult the bash manual.

Comment: Bash manual belongs to one of the most horrifying pieces of software documentation I know :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you are simply trying to get to the other directory, then the solution is to enter it manually (otherwise the system will not follow the link back to its source).

Example:

`cd ~/b/c`

You can assign an alias for this using:

`alias cdtobc="cd ~/b/c"`

(The above is an example, and you can of course substitute values as needed).