# Is there a way to get the trailing '/' to appear when using cd with a symbolic link directory?

Tags: symbolic-link, auto-completion, cd-command

I'm using the bash shell and use lots of soft links.  One minor but annoying behavior I observe is the fact that I need to hit tab twice to complete the name of a soft link to a directory. e.g.

```
$ mkdir dir1
$ ln -s dir1 link1
```

Using autocompletion, entering, "cd d" produces "cd dir1/", but entering "cd l" produces "cd link1", when I'd really like it to produce "cd link1/"

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for the **readline** variables `mark-directories`, and `mark-symlinked-directories`.  Just add the following to your `~/.inputrc` file and re-load it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>x</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>r</kbd>.

```
set mark-directories on
set mark-symlinked-directories on
```

To ensure that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>x</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>r</kbd> works you should also have the following in your `~/.inputrc`.  (See [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/241187/how-do-i-reload-inputrc).)

```
"\C-x\C-r": re-read-init-file
```

Incidentally, if you want to list the current settings of your **readline** variables, use the following command:  (See also `man bash` for more details.)

```
bind -v
```

Comment: Which of these manpages are you referring to, when you say `man bind`? http://manpages.ubuntu.com/cgi-bin/search.py?q=bind

Comment: Sorry, neither one is right.  I should have said `man bash`, as the `bind` command is a bash built-in.  I will edit my answer.

Comment: I was unaware (and did not have) a .inputrc file, but now I do!  Note that the `"\C-x\C-r": re-read-init-file` gave me an error so I removed it.

Answer (score 0):

Tab here is acting as an auto complete, all it does is search for relevant files and directories there to complete your command.

As far as I know, in bash you can not tell it to do other wise, you can try using other shells, maybe they can.

However there isn't really a difference. since both commands will get you to the same directory...

**update**

According to [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/190042/show-the-target-of-current-directorysymbolic-link?rq=1) you can use this to cd to the parenting directory:

> Here is a way of changing to the target of the given symbolic link:
>
> ```
> cd -P .
> ```
>
> Here is how it works
>
> ```
> user@host:~/tmp$ ls 
> @a b
> user@host:~/tmp$ file a
> a: symbolic link to `b/c'
> user@host:~/tmp$ cd a
> user@host:~/tmp/a$ cd .
> user@host:~/tmp/a$ cd -P .a
> user@host:~/tmp/b/c$
> ```
>
> You can alias it to
>
> ```
> cdl='cd -P'
> ```
>
> From the bash manual:
>
> > The **-P** option says to use the physical  directory structure  instead  of following symbolic links

Comment: While this wasn't the solution I was looking for (Mig10 nailed it), knowing about the -P option on cd is pretty cool.  Thanks.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't be of help :-) @mikemtnbikes